# How to add buttons in Angular mat-table?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I've sucessfully used Angular mat-table to display data from database:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IXZX.png)

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="UserDataSourceFilters" class="mat-elevation-z1 mt-5">
            <ng-container [matColumnDef]="column" *ngFor="let column of displayedColumns">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>{{ getUserColumnDisplayName(column) }}</th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let emp">{{ emp[column] }}</td>
            </ng-container>
          
            <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
            <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let emprow; columns: displayedColumns" (click)="onRowExchangeClicked(emprow)"
                [ngClass]="{ 'clicked-row': true  }"></tr>
        </table>

        <mat-paginator [length]="100" [pageSize]="10" [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100, 200]"
            aria-label="Select page">
        </mat-paginator>
```

Now I want to add another column, which contains buttons. So in component.ts, I add a new column called **actions**:

```
displayedColumns: string[] = ['firstName', 'lastName', 'email', ..., 'type','actions'];
```

and in my html i added this container:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
                <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>actions</mat-header-cell>
                <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
                <button mat-button>Edit</button>
                </mat-cell>
            </ng-container>
```

But when i run the project, I got this error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWxaf.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Also, the error is totally expected, as in your code you are already looping over the `displayedColumns`, so the `actions` column is defined twice.

Answer (score 0):

You should separate the displayedColumns from the colDefs like this

```js
colDefs: string[] = ['firstName', 'lastName', 'email', ..., 'type']; // removed the 'actions';

displayedColumns: string[] = [...colDefs, 'actions', 'any additional columns ...'];
```

Then your component should look like this

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="UserDataSourceFilters" class="mat-elevation-z1 mt-5">
            <ng-container [matColumnDef]="column" *ngFor="let column of colDefs">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>{{ getUserColumnDisplayName(column) }}</th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let emp">{{ emp[column] }}</td>
            </ng-container>
            <ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
                <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>actions</mat-header-cell>
                <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
                <button mat-button>Edit</button>
                </mat-cell>
            </ng-container>
          
            <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
            <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let emprow; columns: displayedColumns" (click)="onRowExchangeClicked(emprow)"
                [ngClass]="{ 'clicked-row': true  }"></tr>
        </table>

        <mat-paginator [length]="100" [pageSize]="10" [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100, 200]"
            aria-label="Select page">
        </mat-paginator>
```

Comment: my code is exactly like that.But it's gaving me the same error

Comment: I changed this line if you didn't notice `<ng-container [matColumnDef]="column" *ngFor="let column of colDefs">` so it doesn't include the `actions`